# Linux Slackware MySQL can't move datadir

Tags: mysql, configuration

By default datadir was located in `/usr/lib/mysql`. I decided to move it to a different disk partition: `/mnt/C/mysql`:

```
drwxr-x--- 25 mysql mysql 36864 Feb 25 12:52 mysql
```

I opened `/etc/my.cnf`, but there was no `datadir` command there. So, I added one inside `[mysqld]` block:

```
datadir     = /mnt/C/mysql
```

But when I try to start `mysqld`, it seems to be using the old directory:

```
bash-4.2# /etc/rc.d/rc.mysqld start
mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/mysql/asus.err'.
touch: cannot touch ‘/var/lib/mysql/asus.err’: No such file or directory
chown: cannot access ‘/var/lib/mysql/asus.err’: No such file or directory
mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 107: /var/lib/mysql/asus.err: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /var/lib/mysql/asus.err: No such file or directory
mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysql/mysql.pid ended
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 107: /var/lib/mysql/asus.err: No such file or directory
```

I found the portion of `/usr/bin/mysqld_safe` file, responsible for the error:

```
# Try where the binary installs put it
if test -d $MY_BASEDIR_VERSION/data/mysql
then
  DATADIR=$MY_BASEDIR_VERSION/data
  if test -z "$defaults" -a -r "$DATADIR/my.cnf"
  then
    defaults="--defaults-extra-file=$DATADIR/my.cnf"
  fi
# Next try where the source installs put it
elif test -d $MY_BASEDIR_VERSION/var/mysql
then
  DATADIR=$MY_BASEDIR_VERSION/var
# Or just give up and use our compiled-in default
else
  DATADIR=/var/lib/mysql
fi
```

So, it seems to be using the default dir: `/var/lib/mysql`. I changed it to `/mnt/C/mysql`, but it didn't help.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a symbolic link to new data directory.
When your new data directory is ready to use, stop mysql server and type:

```
rm -r /var/lib/mysql
ln -s /mnt/C/mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Now you can restart mysql server with standard datadir.

Comment: This worked. But why doesn't it allow to change the configs?

Comment: What sets `$MY_BASEDIR_VERSION`?  Beyond that, none of the tests would allow for this syntax:  `/mnt/C/mysql`.